# React native redux loading state order

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I want the getKey function to wait for the updated state from friendExist.
Currently getKey is set to false as the initial state however friendExist should set the boolean to "true". But it seems that "this.props.getKey(this.props.exist)" dosen't wait "this.props.friendExist(uid)" to update before it runs the code.

```
componentDidMount(){
 const uid = 'MZdKuFpGmGRntb0nyF4PO0f6kco1';
 this.props.friendExist(uid);
 //friendExist should update this.props.exist to true 
 this.props.getKey(this.props.exist)
}
```

Both friendExist and getKey are actions that dispatch the new state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `componentDidMount` is a synchronous function, so it will execute inside code without waiting for any unrelated functions. Unless you change its type to asynchronous, and tell exactly how you want it to wait, `this.props.exist` will never be true at the time `this.props.getKey` is executed.

An alternative, simpler solution is taking the update of `this.props.exist` at `componentWillReceiveProps`, and execute `this.props.getKey` in there instead

```
componentDidMount(){
 const uid = 'MZdKuFpGmGRntb0nyF4PO0f6kco1';
 this.props.friendExist(uid);
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps, nextState) {
  if (nextProps.exist) {
    this.props.getKey(nextProps.exist)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using react-redux mapStateToProps() to get the updated state. This behavior is expected as react-redux uses react's setState() internally, which is asynchronous, meaning your state may not map to the props on the same time you dispatch the action.

I suggest creating a function getKeyIfFriendExist() instead which does the dispatching and checking of the latest state inside.